# Keyboard on view event is not working by Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, keyevent

Coding is easy for Keyboard event handling by Kotlin if write the following code

```
    override fun onKeyUp(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
        return when (keyCode) {
            KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER -> {
                ....
                true
            }
            else -> super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event)
        }
    }
}
```

But this event is working for real keyboard device not virtual keyboard on view
Let me know fix way someone....

Answer (score 0):

Omg, I mistook use TextInputLayout not EditText...
Oops, sorry
I fixed the issue